# Excel - Clear specific cells Button

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets. I already have a button to save the data to another sheet called "Data" and it is well working. Now I created one button which needs to do two jobs.  It will clear cells (shown in the code) and then it will put in the cell C2 next consecutive number.

```
Sub ClearButton()
Range("L1", "L2").Clear
Range("C2", "B3").Clear
Range("J5", "K5").Clear
End Sub
```

I want the cell C2 in this Entry sheet to check the column A in another sheet called "Data". In the Data sheet in column A it saves all the customer number as 1,2,3 and carries on. So it must check the last entry or the maximum number in the column A rows. So if the maximum number in Column A(Data Sheet) is 5 then it will put in cell C2(Entry Sheet) 6 so that new entry is done.

Comment: Are you working in Visual Studio? Is the VBA?

Comment: Nope. Just in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
This will grab the last value in column `A` on the sheet `Data`, add 1 to it, and set `C2` on the `ActiveSheet` to the value.

Note that if the data in column `A` on the `Data` sheet is not a number, this may throw an error and need to be handled.

```
Sub ClearButton()
Range("L1", "L2").Clear
Range("C2", "B3").Clear
Range("C2").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("J5", "K5").Clear
End Sub
```